# Como deslogar usuário de todos os dispositivos?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação e essa dúvida me surgiu enquanto fazia alguns testes, onde eu executei algumas alterações, como a mudança de senha, no computador mas meu usuário permaneceu logado no celular. Ou então como alguns outros serviços fazem (stackoverflow, google, etc..), onde existe a opção de deslogar e deslogar em todos os dispositivos.

Estou utilizando `AngularJS` em front end e `PHP` com banco de dados `MySql`.

Minha ideia inicial seria criar um novo campo no BD, como `usuarioLogado` e toda vez que o usuário acessar a página fazer a verificação do valor.

- Sempre que o usuário logar, alterar o valor para 1.
- Sempre que o usuário deslogar, alterar o valor para 0.
- Sempre que o usuário acessar a página e houver histórico de acesso, ou cookie, verificar qual é o valor. Se for `0`, forçar um novo login.

Não sei se essa lógica está correta, levando em consideração a segurança do usuário e a praticidade de se fazer isso.

Ou existe algum outro método mais "correto", mais prático de se obter esse resultado?

Comment: Que tal fazer autenticação via JWT e renovar o token sempre que o usuário quiser deslogar de todos os dispositivos?

Comment: @jbueno humm.. Consegue elaborar uma resposta mais aprofundada nisso? Eu já li um pouco a respeito de JWT, mas nada muito aprofundado, então desconheço o uso.